# How choose image size for adding own Overlay in google map api?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When i try adding my image in google map the image is distorted. Current image size is 5000x2475px. How fix this problem?

Maybe it's due to the parameters swBound and neBound?

Current image params:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = this.image_;
        img.style.width = '100%';
        img.style.height = '100%';
        div.appendChild(img);
```

Maybe exist tool for detect correct swBound and neBound

Comment: What does your image look like?  Why are you specifying 100% size?

Comment: I find method how detect right swBound and neBound - http://www.lotusmarketing.ca/misc/googlemap/

Comment: Does that mean you answered your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered - lotusmarketing.ca/misc/googlemap